# Norm for the energy-momentum vector: what meaning/use does it have from the point of view of the energy-momentum tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, mass-energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Many books on relativity define "mass" $M$ as the norm of the energy-momentum vector $\pmb{P} := (E, \pmb{p})$, that is, $M = \sqrt{\lvert \pmb{P}\cdot\pmb{g}\cdot\pmb{P}\rvert}$, where $\pmb{g}$ is the metric tensor, and where there may be different sign conventions in these definitions. (The claim in many books is that this mass $M$ is constant, although I personally don't quite agree with this claim, as a particle might well have different excitation states. But this isn't the point of this question.)

The energy-momentum vector, however, is a sort of approximation of the energy-momentum(-stress) *tensor* $\pmb{T}$ – the former should be the result of the integration of the latter in a very small volume, so small that the problem of path-dependence of "integration" of a tensor in a curved manifold can be neglected. Admittedly few books explain the relation between the two in a clear way.

My question is this: what is the connection between $M$ (as defined above) and the energy-momentum *tensor* $\pmb{T}$? And how does the meaning or usefulness of $M$ change from the point of view of the energy-momentum tensor?

Comment: I believe $p^\mu = T^{0\mu}$ is the 4-momentum density, and $\rho = g_{\mu\nu}p^\mu p^\nu$ is the mass density.

Comment: Thank you @ErJio. So we'd have $\rho = \sqrt{\lvert T^{0\mu}\,T_{\mu}^{0}\rvert}$. Interesting difference from $T^{00}$.

Comment: You can certainly calculate $T_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$, which is a scalar, but I don't know if it has a physical interpretation.

Comment: @Javier Fair enough, and it shows that my question was trivial or badly targeted, thank you. I have rephrased it now.

Comment: @Javier  by the way, I think that the trace of $\pmb{T}$, also a scalar, is used more often (for instance, the trace for the energy-momentum tensor of an EM field vanishes). But I can't grasp if there's any connection between it and $M$.

Comment: I'll see if I can write an answer later, but for now I can't help to respond to your parenthesis: "invariant" doesn't mean "constant". No one claims that mass is constant - the statement is that, at any given instant, that formula has the same value in all reference frames. After a physical process it might have a different, also invariant, value.

Comment: @Javier Very bad terminology on my part, of course it's invariant by construction. Thank you. But some books do say that it's constant.